# PHP regex: Check if every text row starts with Foo

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

How can I check in PHP if every text row starts with Foo?

I want to remove "Foo" at the beginng of rows, but only if every row starts with Foo.

```
$string = 'Foo A
Foo B
Foo C';

should return:
A
B
C
```

and

```
$string = 'Foo A
B
Foo C';

should return:
Foo A
B
Foo C
```

How could this be matched?

```
if ( preg_match("/^Foo/m", $string ) ) {
  $string = preg_replace('/^Foo /m', '', $string);
}
```

This matches only single rows, but as mentioned it should only apply if all rows start with "Foo ".

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/roZNEo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the regex a bit to assert every line starts with `"Foo"`.

```
if ( preg_match("/^((?:^|\n)Foo.*)+$/", $text ) ) {
    $text = preg_replace('/^Foo /m', '', $text);
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ail50t

Comment: Awesome. What does `(?:^|\n)` exactly do?

Comment: @Martin: The `?:` means non-capturing group (I signal that it should not capture the match, so it is a bit faster). Without the non-capturing group, it can be rewritten as `(^|\n)`, which means start of the string `^`, or new line `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&$count` parameter for `preg_replace` to determine how many replacements have occurred. If that's equal to the number of lines in the text, then every line began with `Foo`.

```
function replace($text) {

    if ( preg_match("/^Foo/m", $text ) ) {
        $return = preg_replace('/^Foo /m', '', $text, -1, $num_matches); 
        if( $num_matches == count( explode( "\n", $text))) {
            $text = $return;
        }
    }

    return $text;
}
```

You could also omit the call to `preg_match`, as it is redundant and unnecessary.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lIKe2B)

Comment: ah, nice trick to count test replacements. gotta keep that in mind. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = 'Foo A
Foo B
Foo C';

$a = explode("\n", $string);

foreach ($a as $line) {
  print preg_replace('/^Foo /', '', $line) . "\n";
}

?>
```

See it in action here:
http://codepad.org/ch6x0hSR

Note that this is overkill for this sample data; you should use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) if you don't really need regular expressions.

Heck, if each line is always formatted `{uselessword}{delimiter}{importantword}`, then you could also use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: This will still fail the OP's second use case - To *not* replace `Foo` in any input where `Foo` is not at the beginning of every line.

Comment: Ah - I think the second case might have been an edit, as I don't recall seeing it when I started answering.  I'll revise.

Comment: Ah, an answer has been picked.  And it's a good one.  Never mind then.  :)